# Maximizing area of the triangle in a quarter circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

> The radius of the quarter circle is $6\sqrt 5$ and we assume that $OA= 5$ and $OC=10$. What is the maximum area of the blue triangle?
>
> [image]

Interpreting the problem statement, I believe that points $A$ and $C$ are fixed and point $B$ can move on the arc. To solve this problem, I assumed that the coordinate of $O$ is $(0,0)$ and then assigned coordinates for each vertex of the triangle: $A(5,0), C(0,10), B(x,\sqrt{180-x^2})$ where $x \in [0, 6\sqrt5]$. Then I applied the formula for the area of the triangle given its vertices, and the problem is reduced to maximizing

$$A(x)= \left|25-(\frac52\sqrt{180-x^2}+5x)\right|\quad \text{for}\quad x \in [0, 6\sqrt5]$$

Which is easy to continue and I got $50$ as the answer.

I'm looking for other approaches to solve this problem. I'm particularly interested in geometric approaches.

Comment: Hint: Max area=>max height of B from base AC. So think of the tangent to the quarter arc which is parallel to AC

Comment: @SohamSaha Nice and intuitive approach! It explains the idea that the height from $B$  to $AC$  should passes through $O$ to maximize the area. One can expand this idea to notice that the minimum area occurs when $B$ is on each endpoint of the arc.

Comment: umm… not exactly, the upper endpoint would be better for minimizing area in this case. Can you see why?

Comment: @SohamSaha Oh true, I wrongly thought $AC$ has the slope of $1$. Obviously the parallel line intersect the upper endpoint first!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to fix at least 1 of A,B or C; perhaps 2 of them? Failing that much, what point could there be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area of the triangle ABC is equal to its side AC multiplied by the height, divided by $2$. The height will be maximal if we draw a radius OB such that OB is perpendicular to AC. Let H be the intersection of AC and OB.

Then $$AC=\sqrt{OC^2+OA^2}=\sqrt{25+100}=5\sqrt5.$$

It is known that $$OH=\frac{OA\cdot OC}{AC}=\frac{5\cdot 10}{5\sqrt5}=2\sqrt5.$$

Then $$HB=OB-OH=6\sqrt5-2\sqrt5=4\sqrt5.$$

Then the area of the triangle ABC is $$\frac{BH\cdot AC}2=\frac{4\sqrt5\cdot 5\sqrt5}2=50.$$

Answer (score 3):

Just extend the circle, call $A'$ and $C'$ the intersection of the line AC with the circle. The middle $B$ of the arc $A'C'$ is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Applying Heron's formula for the area of a triangle as a function of the value of the length of its sides and finding the value of x for which this value has a maximum, we obtain that:

$AC=5\sqrt{5};AB=\sqrt{85};CB=4\sqrt{10}$

being the coordinates of the point B :
$x=12, y=6$.